# Dynamic Text Box Input using C#

Tags: button, dynamic, textbox

Using C#, I have drag and dropped one button using Windows Forms and created one button and text box dynamically.  I would like to display the input from the textbox on the button.  The hard coded button works fine but the dynamic button crashes the program with a System.NullReferenceException.

Please help me learn how to get input from a dynamically created textbox with the click of a dynamically created button.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication8
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Button btnDynamic;
    TextBox txtBoxYear;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        tp();

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = (Button)sender;
        btnHardCode.Text = txtBoxYear.Text;       //This hard coded button works
       // btnDynamic.Text = txtBoxYear.Text;   //The dynamic button crashes the program with a 
                                            //System.NullReferenceException
    }
    private void tabPage1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void tp()  //put textbox and button on tab on tab click
    {
        var tab = tabControl1.TabPages[0];
        //tab.Controls.Clear();
        var btnDynamic = new Button()
        {
            Size = new Size(75, 30),
            Left = 40,
            Top = 50,
            Text = "try",
        };
        btnDynamic.Click += new EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
        tab.Controls.Add(btnDynamic);
        txtBoxYear = new TextBox()
        {
            Size = new Size(200, 100),
            Left = 20,
            Top = 10,
        };
        tab.Controls.Add(txtBoxYear);

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to get input from a dynamically created textbox with the click of a dynamically created button. First, declare the name of the button at the class level.  Second, when instantiating the button object, do not use the var keyword as I did above.  Instantiate it like this:
    btnDynamic = new Button()

Here is the functioning code:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace dynamicButton
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        TextBox txtBoxYear;
        Button btnDynamic;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            tp();
        }


        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                Button btn = (Button)sender;
                btnHardCode.Text = txtBoxYear.Text;
                btnDynamic.Text = txtBoxYear.Text;         
        }
        private void tabPage1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void tp()  //put textbox and button on tab on tab click
        {
            var tab = tabControl1.TabPages[0];
            //tab.Controls.Clear();
            btnDynamic = new Button()
            {
                Size = new Size(100, 30),
                Left = 40,
                Top = 50,
                Text = "DynamicButton",
            };
            btnDynamic.Click += new EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
            tab.Controls.Add(btnDynamic);
            txtBoxYear = new TextBox()
            {
                Size = new Size(200, 100),
                Left = 20,
                Top = 10,
            };
            tab.Controls.Add(txtBoxYear);

        }

        private void btnHardCode_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```